# Ecto declare schema for a query

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to run this query:

```
select last_sd.*
from
  (select distinct(sensor_id) from sensor_data) s LEFT JOIN LATERAL
  (select * from sensor_data sd1 where sd1.sensor_id = s.sensor_id order by sd1.received_at desc limit 1) last_sd ON true
```

the closest I got is:

```
from s in IotInABox.SensorData, distinct: true, select: s.sensor_id
|> join(:left_lateral, [s], sd in fragment("select * from sensor_data sd1 where sd1.sensor_id = ? order by sd1.received_at desc limit 1", s.sensor_id))
|> select([s, sd], sd)
```

this however works partially, since it throws

```
PostgreSQL requires a schema module when using selector "f1" but none was given. Please specify a schema or specify exactly which fields from "f1" you desire in query
```

meaning that since I don't have `from s in SensorData` it doesn't know which ecto model to use,

is there a way to tell ecto which schema use as the query result?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not perfect but something like this works for me (using names from my project in example below):

```
keys = Division.__schema__(:fields)
query = from d in "divisions", select: map(d, ^keys)
result = Repo.all(query) |> Enum.map(&(struct(Division, &1)))
```

1. First you need list of schema fields
2. Select all keys in form of map
3. Map your maps back to structs ^^

Comment: Yeah I've read that solution in another answer but I would like to just declare the schema, now I could just join back again on the schema but it will affect performance

Comment: I doubt if there is other way than `from s in SensorData` for declaring schema

Comment: @alex88 maybe you should try Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query with your raw sql and then convert %Postgrex.Result{} to what you want